# Trigger IF statement will not fire

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have a trigger that has an If statement in it, that if statement should pick up any new lead assigned to the Pre Qual queue. This Queue is set when I manually create a new lead and click the use assignment box. The trigger should do a lookup to get the queue id and if the queue is equal to the owner id then it continues with the rest of the code in an apex class. I can not get it to fire on the IF statement. Ive hardcoded the queue id and that does not work, Ive hard coded my user id and unchecked the assignment rule on createing a new lead and it will work. If I comment out the if statement then it works.

Ive also ran the select statement in the developer console and confirmed that the statement gets the correct queue id. not sure what to do next, any thoughts?

```
trigger LeadTriggerHandler on Lead (after insert) {
    // Get the queue Id
    Group queue = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperName = 'Pre_Qual'];

    for(Lead lead : Trigger.new) {
        // Check if the Lead is assigned to the queue
         if(lead.OwnerId == queue.Id) {
            IonAPIService.sendLeadInfo(lead.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `OwnerId` being set in the first place? You may be hitting an issue with [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), as `after triggers` execute before `assignment rules`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment rules run *after* the after insert triggers, so `OwnerId` will be the user who created the record if unset, or the specified user or queue if set from the parent transaction. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). Use a Record-Triggered After Save Flow instead.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that could have been the case. If the Owner is set to the Queue in Pardot, do you think that would solve the issue? In production that is actually how the leads would come in.

Comment: @Sgrove It should work as you expect in that case. It's only the timing of assignment rules versus triggers that matter here.